# How to show/hide divs when select options are clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select box and want to show a help text in a hidden div when you click on an option:

```
<select  onchange="optionCheck()" multiple="multiple" name="test" id="options" size="15" class="form-select">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="help1" style=visibility:hidden>help text 1</div>
<div id="help2" style=visibility:hidden>help text 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function optionCheck(){
        var option = document.getElementById("options").value;
        if(option == "1"){
            document.getElementById("help1").style.visibility ="visible";
            document.getElementById("help2").style.visibility ="hidden";
        }
        if(option == "2"){
            document.getElementById("help2").style.visibility ="visible";
            document.getElementById("help1").style.visibility ="hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I create a simple loop so I don't have to write "if" statements for each option?

```
 document.getElementById(option).style.visibility ="visible";
```

isn't working - javascript and me don't get along well ;-)

Also, is there a simple way to hide all other divs when an option is selected?

Comment: first off, it's not good practice to define your events in your html. These days there are good alternatives available (all defining them in your javascript) and this relies on a string getting `eval`ed, and that's just no good.

Comment: Second, you should put quotes around `visibility:hidden`. It may not break your code at this moment, but that's no reason to do it like this. You also just shouldn't use style properties, but we'll pretend we didn't see that.

Comment: Are all of your options going to be numbered, and are the div's going to be given ids of "help_" where the underscore is a corresponding number?

Comment: yes, they are all numbered like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

First, I'm pretty lazy, and I don't want to type style="visibility: hidden;" on each of those divs. It's easier to hide all of them at once with CSS:

HTML:

```
<select  onchange="optionCheck()" multiple="multiple" name="test" id="options" size="15" class="form-select">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="help-wrapper">
  <div id="help1">help text 1</div>
  <div id="help2">help text 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#help-wrapper div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* It's better to use a class to highlight the selection,
   in case you feel like adding more styles later (like a border or something).
 */
.current-help {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Now we can work on making that Javascript a little more generic:

```
function optionCheck()
{
  var i;
  var optionIndex = document.getElementById("options").value;

  var helpWrapper = document.getElementById("help-wrapper");
  var helpDivs = helpWrapper.getElementsByTagName("div");

  // Loop through all the help divs.
  for (i=0; i<helpDivs.length; i++) {
    // Parse out the numeric portion of this help div's id.
    var helpIndex = helpDivs[i].substring[4];

    // If we found our div, highlight it.
    if (helpIndex === optionIndex) {
      helpDivs[i].className = "current-help";
    }
    // Otherwise, we should make sure it's hidden,
    // in case it was the previous selection.
    else {
      helpDivs[i].className = "";
    } 
  }
}
```

And that should do the trick!

If you have any questions about the code above, I'd be happy to answer them.

Comment: `helpDiv.style.display = "inline-block";` is also an option. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using some CSS classes to hide/show the divs. Then the JavaScript just needs to set the class attribute for each div.

This solution still works if you select more than one option.

HTML:

```
<select onchange="optionCheck()" multiple="multiple" name="test" id="options" size="15" class="form-select">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="help1" class="helpText">help text 1</div>
<div id="help2" class="helpText">help text 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* consider "display: none/block" instead of visibility: hidden/visible
   if you don't want the hidden divs to occupy space */
.helpText {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.helpTextShow {
    visibility: visible;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
function optionCheck() {
    var i, len, optionVal, helpDiv,
        selectOptions = document.getElementById("options");

    // loop through the options in case there
    // are multiple selected values
    for (i = 0, len = selectOptions.options.length; i < len; i++) {

        // get the selected option value
        optionVal = selectOptions.options[i].value;

        // find the corresponding help div
        helpDiv = document.getElementById("help" + optionVal);

        // move on if we didn't find one
        if (!helpDiv) { continue; }

        // set CSS classes to show/hide help div
        if (selectOptions.options[i].selected) {
            helpDiv.className = "helpText helpTextShow";
        } else {
            helpDiv.className = "helpText";
        }
    }    
}

// alternative method of binding the onchange handler, merely a suggestion
//document.getElementById("options").onchange = optionCheck;
```

​

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/3N9pm/9/

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't account for the multiple selection. I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Ok, after a few tries that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the modified HTML and JavaScript code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="help1" style="display:none">help text 1</div>
<div id="help2" style="display:none">help text 2</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function optionCheck()
{
    var option = document.getElementById("options").value;
    if(option == "1"){
        document.getElementById("help1").style.display ="";
        document.getElementById("help2").style.display ="none";
    }
    if(option == "2"){
        document.getElementById("help2").style.display ="";
        document.getElementById("help1").style.display ="none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to wrap css styles with quotes:

```
  <div id="help1" style="visibility:hidden">help text 1</div>
  <div id="help2" style="visibility:hidden">help text 2</div>


function optionCheck(){
        var option = document.getElementById("options").value;
        document.getElementById("help" + option).style.visibility ="visible";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getElementById(option)`, try something like `getElementById("help" + option)`.

Comment: What is `getElementById("help" + option)`?

Comment: The poster said that:
`document.getElementById(option).style.visibility ="visible";`
isn't working.  In part, at least, that's because `option` is "1" or "2", whereas the element ID is "help1" or "help2".

So, try `"help" + option` rather than just `option`.

Comment: cool, that worked. How can I hide all other divs when one has been selected?

Comment: Pseudocode (I'm not totally javascriptish off the top of my head):

`for (i = 1; i <= numOptions; ++i) {
   if (i == option) {
      visibilityValue = "visible";
   } else {
      visibilityValue = "hidden";
   }
   document.getElementById("help" + option).style.visibility = visibilityValue;
}`   ... and presumably you previously set "numOptions" to 2 (or whatever the appropriate value is)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with ternary operator in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("options").value == 1?(document.getElementById("help1").style.visibility ="visible",document.getElementById("help2").style.visibility ="hidden"):(document.getElementById("help2").style.visibility ="visible",document.getElementById("help1").style.visibility ="hidden");
```

This will avoid multiple if statements